# objdump shows different function names

Tags: g++

I have a cpp file that was compiled into an object file. For some reason, the functions inside the cpp file are named differently so one of the functions is "undefined". I don't know why g++ would label the functions differently.

Here are the relevant objdump output:

```
root@0b8da3d55c14:~/GF# g++ -g -Wall -o polynomial_arith.o -c polynomial_arith.cpp 
root@0b8da3d55c14:~/GF# objdump -t polynomial_arith.o | grep Add
0000000000000219 g     F .text  00000000000001fc _Z13polynomialAddPKxsS0_sPxsx
root@0b8da3d55c14:~/GF# objdump -t polynomial_arith.o | grep Sub
0000000000000462 l     F .text  0000000000000019 _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_iPxsx
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000219 _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_iPxsx
root@0b8da3d55c14:~/GF# objdump -t test.o | grep Add
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _Z13polynomialAddPKxsS0_sPxsx
root@0b8da3d55c14:~/GF# objdump -t test.o | grep Sub
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_sPxsx
```

You can see that polynomialAdd is _Z13polynomialAddPKxsS0_sPxsx in the object file while polynomialSub is _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_iPxsx. The test function (test.o) expects _Z13polynomialAddPKxsS0_sPxsx and _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_sPxsx. Thus polynomialSub is undefined because its name in polynomial_arith.o is _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_iPxsx, while polynomialAdd is just fine.

Are there special meaning to _iPxsx vs. SPxsx, and why they are generated differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ demumble _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_iPxsx
polynomialSub(long long const*, short, long long const*, int, long long*, short, long long)
$ demumble _Z13polynomialSubPKxsS0_sPxsx
polynomialSub(long long const*, short, long long const*, short, long long*, short, long long)
```

They are different functions with different parameters.

Comment: ah, I got it now. One is short, the other is int. Thx!